# Civicrm altering contribution page

Tags: civicontribute, custom-fields, contributions, payment-processor, taxes

I have been struggling for weeks now trying to figure out the best way to prepare a form where :

- user selects province, apply a tax based on the province
- user selects the membership priceset
- total updated with the new membership price and tax according to the province selected.

is there any reference of key of achieving this? is this possible or not possible? I have been trying to use civitax but that's not the way to use it, and I tried adding mulitple tax field or trying to find conditional methods but that is not populating.

I am thinking of setting up the form in drupal custom form, then after that populate it via custom submit where when it submits, it manually db insert the transactions and all of that? but is that possible, as I search no clue of programmatically inserting/creating new user with membership info and so on.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

How many different tax rates are involved?

It there aren't too many, a no-tech solution would be to create a different price set for each different tax rate and have province-based links on your call to action page.

Added later:

I don't know a lot about the tax feature but I put down what I **think** might work. (This is all untested so could be totally wrong.) Assuming you have already ticked **enable  tax and invoicing** at **Administer > CiviContribute > CiviContribute Component setttings**, I would have thought you might need to:

- create three different financial account with the different tax rates say tax2, tax3, tax4.
- create three different financial types member_dues2, member_dues3, member_dues4
- edit the three different financial types  to link each to the appropriate sales tax account
- edit the three different financial accounts you will now have, to set the account code to the same value for each so that that membership revenue can totalled across aall the provinces using a line item report  (if this is a what you need.)
  -Create a price set for each province lined to the correct financial type.

If this doesn't work, my apologies, but it may help you on your way somehow.

Comment: how do we trigger the rate on pricesets? we have 3 types of tax, 2%, 3% and 4% based on specific province that users select @JoAnne

Comment: I have expanded my answer to include my response to you comment.  It was too complicated ot put in a comment.